# Read data excel without openning file using ADODB VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, adodb

I tried to read excel data and display it to Datagrid but after executing the function there was an error 'Unable to cast object of type' System.Data.DataTable 'to type' System.Collections.IEnumerable '.'

```
Private Sub LoadFile()
    Dim file As String = "D:\Test.xlsx;"

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rec As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    With con
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & file &
                            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
        .Open()
    End With

    Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

    With rec
        .CursorLocation = CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        .Open(qry, con, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset,
              LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)
        .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With

    gridview.ItemsSource = Display(rec) "Error in this line"

    rec.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

And this for Display data to Datagrid

```
Public Function Display(ByVal objRS As ADODB.Recordset) As DataTable

    Dim objDA As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim objDT As New DataTable()
    objDA.Fill(objDT, objRS)
    Return objDT

End Function
```

I really appreciate your answer efforts all

Comment: Replace the `ADODB.Connection` with an `OleDbConnection` and dump the Recordset. Use an `OleDbCommand` instead of `OleDbDataAdapter` and call [DataTable].Load([DataReader]) using the OleDbDataReader returned by `OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()`. All objects declared with `Using` statements. Now, what is a GridView? Is it the WPF DataGrid, which requires an IEnumerable as source? Do you have System.Data.DataSetExtensions there?

Comment: In that case, you may want to convert you DataTable to, e.g., an [ObservableCollection<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1). -- Tag your question specifying the Platform and the objects you're using.

Comment: using wpf datagrid no have System.Data.DataSetExtensions